# code showing lvalue error

Tags: c++

My code has an error

> **prog.cpp** 
>    To compare two given two string of same length and to
>   give the required output to user for example if str1 is greater than the other string.

```
      #include<iostream>
      #include<cstring>
      using namespace std;

   int main()

     {    
       int i=0;


         char  str1[10],str2[10];

          cin>>str1>>str2;

          if(strlen(str1)!=strlen(str2)) return 0;

         while(str1[i]!='\n'){

        if(str1[i]>='A'&&str1[i]<='Z') str1[i]=str1[i]+32;
       if(str2[i]>='A'&&str2[i]<='Z') str2[i]=str2[i]+32;
         str1++;   //is there any over here??
          }

        int result=strcmp(str1,str2);
         if(result==0) cout<<"0";
         else if(result>0) cout<<"1";
         else cout<<"-1";
            // printing values..
     return 0;

         }
```

Comment: Removed C# tag, The question has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: And with c, I guess..

Comment: And the body looks like a question template.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually this isn't C++-CLI either, none of the tags are correct

Comment: Fix your indentation please.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? WHat inputs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
    str1++;   //is there any over here??
```

You may want `++i;` here instead.

`str1` is an array and itself cannot be increased.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is an array and array can't be an assignable lvalue

```
str1++;
```

is same as

```
str1 = str1 + 1;
```

So there is an error.

PS: Arrays are not assignable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 str1++;   //is there any over here??
```

is not right. This should be a compiler error.

What you need is:

```
while(str1[i]!='\n')
{
   if(str1[i]>='A'&&str1[i]<='Z') str1[i]=str1[i]+32;
   if(str2[i]>='A'&&str2[i]<='Z') str2[i]=str2[i]+32;

   // Just increment the array index.
   ++i;
}
```